# calling vb.net function of .ascx from javascript which is also in .ascx

Tags: javascript, vb.net

i have a vb.net function which i want to call from javascript both are in .ascx.
In this code i am using a jquery to popup a dialog and on click of the button(btnok) on dialog i want to call a function loadgraph() whihch is a vb.net function.

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="javascript/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;


    $(function() {
        $( "#element_to_pop_up" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });

        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            $( "#element_to_pop_up" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });

         $( "#btnok" ).click(function(){
          $( "#element_to_pop_up" ).dialog( "close" );
             $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Schart.ascx/loadgraph",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
    alert("called")
  }
});
          return false;
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to use is known as [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) - however, page method code (the static method) has to be part of some page (aspx) code behind. You cannot place page method code in user control (ascx) code behind.
I suspect the reason for this limitation is that urls ending with `.ascx` are not meant for client consumption (you will get 404) - they are purely meant for server side manipulation.

For you, the simple solution is to move the relevant method in the page (aspx) code behind and change the url such as `"Schart.aspx/loadgraph"`. You can always keep all the code in ascx file and call it from a dummy page method code and thereby keeping the related UI and code within ascx file.